# IronPython Lists, Tuples, Dictionaries crash WCF communications

Tags: wcf, ironpython

I am attempting to use WCF to execute IronPython remotely inside of C#. Everything in my system is functioning beautifully as long as it is local.

I have isolated the problem to passing certain objects to the client via WCF:

If you try to pass these to a WCF client from a WCF server, the communications channel crashes:

1. PythonDictionaries containing values that are Tuples or Lists
2. Tuples of any kind

...Strangely, dictionaries containing dictionaries are ok (as long as the nested dictionary doesn't meet these 2 conditions). Here is my example code:

```
try
{
    PythonFlow localPython = new PythonFlow();
    IPythonFlow remotePython = new IronTesterWcfClient("localhost", "8000");

    string tuple = "(1,2,3)";
    string list = "[1,2,3]";
    string complexDict0 = "{'a':'b','c':{'d':'f'}}";
    string complexDict1 = "{'a':'b','c':(1,2,3),'e':'e'}";
    string complexDict2 = "{'a':'b','c':[1,2,3],'d':'e'}"; 
    string complexDict3 = "{'a':'b','c':[1,2,3],'d':(1,2,3),'e':{'a':'b','c':[1,2,3],'d':(1,2,3)}}";

    localPython.OpenFlow(args[2]);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.List list1 = localPython.PythonListFromString(list);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict0 = localPython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict0);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict1 = localPython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict1);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict2 = localPython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict2);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict3 = localPython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict3);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple tuple1 = localPython.PythonTupleFromString(tuple);

    remotePython.OpenFlow(args[2]);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.List list2 = remotePython.PythonListFromString(list);
    //OK
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict5 = remotePython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict0);
    //Fail!!!
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict6 = remotePython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict1);
    //Fail!!!
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict7 = remotePython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict2);
    //Fail!!!
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary dict8 = remotePython.PythonDictionaryFromString(complexDict3);
    //Fail!!!
    IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple tuple2 = remotePython.PythonTupleFromString(tuple);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I am using NetTcpBinding with SecurityMode.None on the WCF server side... I should also mention that the python call is ultimately accessing a simple object in python which returns the result of eval()

It's basically making it impossible to use Python with WCF. Any ideas?

More info... I was finally able to extract the exceptions inside WCF when this happens:

Outer Exception:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://Intel.ServiceModel.Samples:TestResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'Type 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple' with data contract name 'ArrayOfanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Inner Exception:

> Type 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple' with data contract name 'ArrayOfanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Comment: You're having the server execute arbitrary remote code?  This is a security hazard.

Comment: It is not an open environment, security (at this level) is not a priority at the moment (let's just get the darn thing working, shall we?) :)

Comment: More info... I was finally able to extract the exceptions inside WCF when this happens:

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `SerializationException`, indicating that .NET doesn't know how to deserialize some chunk of the data you're sending. In this case, it's choking on `ArrayOfanyType`, which is any kind on non-generic collection (an `ArrayList` or plain array, for instance).

I've reviewed the source for IronPython 2.7.1 (what version are you using?), looking at the implementation of `List` and `PythonTuple`. Both contain an Object array, pretty much identically declared; List has a few other random instance fields.

```
// IronPython.Runtime.List
internal volatile object[] _data;
private const int INITIAL_SIZE = 20;
internal int _size;

// IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple
internal readonly object[] _data;
```

I don't know why the serializer isn't happy with the `PythonTuple` class, when it's fine with `List`.  What this probably indicates, however, is that .NET's type resolver can't resolve some element of the serialized object.

There are two ways to resolve this, that I know of.

1. You can try to convince .NET to consider a given type during deserialization, using the [`KnownTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx):

   > When data arrives at a receiving endpoint, the WCF runtime attempts to deserialize the data into an instance of a common language runtime (CLR) type. The type that is instantiated for deserialization is chosen by first inspecting the incoming message to determine the data contract to which the contents of the message conform. The deserialization engine then attempts to find a CLR type that implements a data contract compatible with the message contents. The set of candidate types that the deserialization engine allows for during this process is referred to as the deserializer's set of "known types."

   You'd want to apply this attribute to the class being transferred over the wire, and this isn't convenient when you don't control the class, as is the case here. So this is probably a non-starter.
2. You can specify a custom [`DataContractResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759.aspx) to resolve your problematic types:

   > A data contract resolver allows you to configure known types dynamically. Known types are required when serializing or deserializing a type not expected by a data contract.

   You can do this without controlling the class to be serialized, but it takes a bit more work. [This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx) has a great writeup.

In summary, you'd create a DataContractResolver and override its two methods, `TryResolveType` and `ResolveName`. The first is used during serialization, and the second during deserialization. From the MSDN sample, with my comments:

```
public class MyCustomerResolver : DataContractResolver
{
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type dataContractType, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        if (dataContractType == typeof(Customer)) // a type I recognize
        {
            XmlDictionary dictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            typeName = dictionary.Add("SomeCustomer");
            typeNamespace = dictionary.Add("www.FPSTroller.com");
            return true;
        }
        else  // I don't know what this is; defer to the inbuilt type resolver
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(dataContractType, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
        }
    }

    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        // my type
        if (typeName == "SomeCustomer" && typeNamespace == "http://www.FPSTroller.com")
        {
            return typeof(Customer);
        }
        else // I don't know what this is; defer to the inbuilt type resolver
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The blog post I mentioned above has some sample resolvers that might give .NET a better shot and handling your classes without writing anything custom (look for the "*Useful resolvers*" heading).

You'd use `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior`. To plug your resolver into WCF; see the sample in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.datacontractserializeroperationbehavior.aspx).

Finally, before going down this path, you might consider changing your WCF operations interface. Do you really need to pass these custom, non-generic types over the wire? What I've read implies that non-generic types run into this kind of issue often. Consider using a plain old `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>` and (if you're using .NET 4+) `System.Tuple`. Lock down your types; don't make the resolver guess.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know the OP, and I'm trying to help out; that's why I've also placed a bounty on this question. Someone who knows more than I do, please write a better answer!

Comment: Thanks Mike! I tried these approaches earlier today and settled on updating the wcf interface to not need these types to be transmitted for the same reasons you list. Big pain, big rewrite. Oh well... It just makes no sense that these types can't be serialized.